# Accessing local variables directly through the stack pointer without the base pointer?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, x86-16

While coding an assembly code, can I directly use the stack pointer to access function parameters and local variables without saving the base pointer into the stack and setting the new base pointer in the called function?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in 32 bit and 64 bit assembly you can use the stack pointer with ESP and RSP respectively to access local variables. The reason for using a base stack pointer to access variables is that it's always at a constant location versus the stack pointer which may change location on a push or pop. This would cause you to keep track of how many pushes and pops you do and adjust the variables location accordingly. Look at this for an example: (This is x64)

```
sub rsp, 16   ; Align stack

mov DWORD PTR[rsp], 4
mov DWORD PTR[rsp + 4], 20
mov QWORD PTR[rsp + 8], 175

push 25     ; Push 25 to the stack.
push 50     ; Push 8 to the stack.
...
```

Now if later in your code you wanted to access the variables you placed into the stack at the beginning, their locations have changed because of the push statement. A push statement is equivalent to:

```
sub rsp, 8
mov QWORD PTR[rsp], 45
```

If you tried to access the variables as you placed them in the stack, you will get the wrong number.

```
mov rax, QWORD PTR[rsp + 8]   ; This is not 175, since you did two pushes
                              ; and moved the stack pointer back another 16 bytes.
                              ; You will get 25 as the answer.
```

Now your going to have to keep track manually of how many pushes you've done and adjust the variables location to access them. You can see how much of a problem this is going to cause when your project gets larger.

Now if you use a stack base pointer to access variables it's location is constant and you can access them at the same location everytime (As long as you don't modify the base pointer itself)

```
push rbp      ; Save the old value of RBP.
mov rbp, rsp
sub rsp, 16   ; Align stack

mov DWORD PTR[rbp - 4], 4
mov DWORD PTR[rbp - 8], 20
mov QWORD PTR[rbp - 16], 175

push 25     ; Push 25 to the stack.
push 50     ; Push 8 to the stack.
...

mov eax, DWORD PTR[rbp - 8]  ; This will give you 20 because the
                             ; stack base pointer's location is constant to
                             ; the variables in the stack. The push statements
                             ; only affect the stack pointers location, not the
                             ; base pointer.
...
mov rsp, rbp
pop rbp    ; After you pop the previous pushed values.
```

Answer (score 2):

In 32-bit (IA-32) and 64-bit code (x86-64) yes, in 16-bit code (8086 ... 80286) no. `sp` cannot be used in addressing in any way, `esp` and `rsp` can.

[Wikipedia has a useful list of possible x86 and x86 addressing modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes).

Using `bp` or some other register that can be used for addressing (`bx`, `si`, `di`) is only needed in 16-bit code.

Comment: This does work for local variables. Not using BP doesn't preclude you from subtracting something from SP.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze You're right, but I think you can't know precisely how much stack the interrupt[s] will use. If you use the standard `mov bp/ebp/rsp, sp/esp/rsp; sub sp/esp/rsp, something`, then your local variables are safe independently of the number of interrupts triggered and independently of how much stack the interrupts use.

Comment: The first thing you do in the function is subtract from SP the cumulative size of all the local variables in the function. After that ISRs won't be able to overwrite them unless they're buggy or the CPU is buggy. When you're done with the locals, you add their size back to SP. Simple and safe.

Comment: The stack size itself has nothing to do with using BP or not using BP. You should always have enough stack for ISRs. How much depends on your OS or whatever it is you have in its place.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your message, I thought you meant something like `localvar1 equ -1024`, `mov [rsp + localvar1], dword 0x12345678`... Of course `bp` has nothing to do with this (except in 16-bit code).

Comment: No, that's what *you* seem to mean. :)

Comment: Right, clarified that part of my answer :)

Comment: I don't think this part is necessary, it wasn't asked about. Further, there are 3 other registers that can be used instead of BP: BX, SI, DI. So, even BP may not be needed depending on how the code is structured.

Comment: Yeah, I'm well aware that `bp` is not the only option, although it's commonly used and the only one that has `ss` as its default segment. And you're right, that part is unnecessary, so I cut it off.

Comment: How is that interrupts can interfere with accessing local variables through ESP? Aren't registers restored to their original values after an interrupt has been handled?

Comment: @phant0m Well, if you didn't subtract the size of the stack frame from `esp` (eg. `sub esp,8`) but instead did something crazy like `[mov esp+0xfffffff8], dword 0x12345678` (referencing to smaller memory addresses with a negative immmediate value), then when `cs:eip` is pushed to stack upon hardware interrupt it would overwrite the value you just wrote there. Normally hardware interrupts should restore the original values of the registers, but local variables are in stack, not in registers.

Comment: Ah I understand, but having local variables in the red zone would then not only be a problem when using the stack pointer rather than the base pointer to store local variables, right? I assumed the interrupt handler might not properly restore the stack pointer afterwards, so your wouldn't be able to access local variables through the stack pointer anymore, but through the base pointer it would still work. Now I realize, that this doesn't make sense anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You can do that if you use ESP or RSP, but not SP because there's no SP-relative memory addressing, only ESP-relative and RSP-relative.

Comment: Also... `[ebp + 8]` will store the 8 as a signed byte. Due to an oddity in the instruction encoding, there's no signed byte form for `[esp + 8]` - it will take four bytes to store the 8. I suspect (guessing!) that the situation is worse for `rsp`.

Comment: @FrankKotler Displacements in ModR/M instructions are still limited to 32 bits in 64-bit mode. Only a handful of instructions like `mov reg, imm` have 64-bit integers encoded in them.